# How to get academic year using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var year = new Date().getFullYear();
var lastyear = new Date().getFullYear()-1;
var range = [];
var lastrange = [];
lastrange.push(lastyear);
range.push(year);
  for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++) 
  {
    lastrange.push(lastyear + i);
    range.push(year + i);
    var fullyear = lastrange.concat(range);
   }
$scope.years = fullyear;
```

How to get academic year as a 2017-18,2018-19 like this.
Kindly help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what is it returning now...?? an Array

Comment: right now it is returning an array  **[2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023]**  do you wish **2023-16* or something else

Comment: can you provide us an expectet output?

Comment: Expected Output is 2016-17,2017-18,2018-19 I need to show in ng repeat

Comment: so it would be better if you manipulate your data while insertion..

Comment: I will use a very easy appproach & add the desired output to another result array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am taking a new String array

> var academicYear=[];

which will be filled during the execution of the loop

```
academicYear.push(lastrange[i-1]+"-"+(lastrange[i]).toString().slice(-2));// 2016-17
```

here is a working sample ..

```js
var year = new Date().getFullYear();
var lastyear = new Date().getFullYear()-1;
var range = [];
var lastrange = [];
var academicYear=[];
lastrange.push(lastyear);
range.push(year);
  for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++) 
  {
    lastrange.push(lastyear + i);    
    range.push(year + i);
    academicYear.push(lastrange[i-1]+"-"+(lastrange[i]).toString().slice(-2));
    var fullyear = lastrange.concat(range);
   }
console.log(academicYear);
```

Comment: so is the above code ok...or do i need to do some slight modifications ??

Comment: I have changed the name of **resultresultArray** to **academicYear**

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the `fullyear` and check if the next item exists.
The take the last two characters of the next item and append them with an `-`.

For example:

```
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < fullyear.length; i++) {
    if (fullyear[i + 1]) {
        var academicYear = fullyear[i] + "-" + fullyear[i + 1].toString().slice(-2);
        result.push(academicYear);
    }
}
console.log(result.join());
```

That will result in :

```
2016-17,2017-18,2018-19,2019-20,2020-21,2021-22,2022-17,2017-18,2018-19,2019-20,2020-21,2021-22,2022-23
```